# Why does `killall node` executed on SSH terminal require a restart of the VS Code instance running on Windows - Is there a better option?

Tags: visual-studio-code, ssh

I'm running VS Code on Windows, and SSH into a Ubuntu machine.

Executing `killall node` and sending the command to the remote machine causes the local VS Code instance to require restart - Presumably to rebind the SSH connection locally(?).

This is bad for workflow.

Is there a better way to kill all node processes on the remote machine without destroying VD Code requiring to reconnect?

`lsof -i -P -n | grep LISTEN` reveals that we might be able to get away with just killing IPv6-bound processes - Can these be targeted as a group (Somehting like `killall node ipv6`)?

A note that `killall node` is the only way ensure the node process is killed and a port conflict doesn't arise. Every other conceivable method, `kill -9`  on the process etc, both on the command line and in the code base through `SIGINT` have been tried.

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting to try commands `pkill` and learn about `pgrep` on remote machine.

```
pkill -9 -f node
```

Also suggesting to write a bash script:

#### nodes_killer

```
#!/bin/bash
killall node
```

Than give nodes_killer execution permissions

```
chmod a+x nodes_killer
```

Than try to call `nodes_killer` remotely.

This might guard your VSC from the `killall` command.

Comment: Alas we've tried all these too (at least with zsh).... Everything kills the local VSC